# graphs - Algorithm to move through a graph with positive nodes and negative edges

Tags: algorithm, graph, pseudocode

I have a graph with some positive values in the nodes ad some negative values in the edges. 

I have to move in the graph exactly `x` times, from a source node to a destination node, the goal is to maximize the total of sums:

- when I stay in a node for a move
- subtractions when I pass through an edge

So, if I stay for a move in the same node the sum is increased, so if I stay in a node with value 10 for 4 times I gain 40 as total. An example is in the image below.

[image]

In this case the best solution is:

Move1  -> (source node +3) 3

Move2  -> (3-20+15)     -2

Move3  -> (stay +15)        13

...(stay same node)...

Move19 -> (stay +15)        253

Move20 -> (destination node 253-5+3) 251

What could be an efficient solution to solve the problem? I can implement just something like a pseudocode, just to understand how can I solve it.

Thank you very much.

Comment: What's the scale of the graph (how many nodes in it?) What's the scale of the number of moves required?

Comment: The number of moves is enough to cross the graph I suppose. It is assumed that **x** is always large enough to solve the problem.
The problem asks to solve for a generic number V of nodes and E of edges given a number x of moves.

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved with a variation of [Bellman-Ford algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellman%E2%80%93Ford_algorithm), with `O(|E|*n)` time complexity, where `|E|` is number of edges and `n` is number of steps:

For simplicity, assume you also have a self loop in every node, with weight 0, this represents the "stay operation". So you have have:

```
for all u in V:
(u,u) in E
w(u,u) = 0
```

Now, apply the recursive formula using [Dynamic Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming):

```
D[v][0] = 0          if v is the source
          -infinity  otherwise
D[v][i] = max { D[u][i-1] + w(u,v) + cost(v) | where (u,v) is an edge }
```

The solution is `D[target][n]`

This is basically Bellman-Ford algorithm (with `max` instead of `min`), but you stop after `n` iterations instead of after `|V|`.

Comment: +1, but for me it's easier to visualise if we suppose there are multiple copies of the original graph, one for each time step (think of each copy as a "slice" in a vertical stack of graphs), and force edges from vertices in slice i to go to vertices in slice i+1, with an additional edge from each vertex in slice i to its own copy in slice i+1.  Then BFS will find the answer (using the same recursive formula and time complexity as you give, but it's now clear that we only need to update distances to vertices we have already visited and their neighbours).

Comment: @j_random_hacker But that's exactly what BellmanFord does anyway. The only difference here is you stop after `n` iterations, instead of after `|V|` iterations, and with very small modification to the graph (self loops). Recall that BF also updates nodes it has already found (that's why it is more robust than Dijkstra's algorithm and can handle negative weights).

Comment: The BF algorithm described on the Wikipedia page you link to will waste time trying to update irrelevant and even unreachable edges on every outermost iteration, where BFS won't.  (Consider a graph where there are O(1) edges in the component containing `source`, but other components contain Omega(n^2) "useless" edges.)  Possibly the improvement that BFS gives here coincides (or at least overlaps) with "Yen's first improvement", but this isn't obvious.

Comment: Yes it's correct, but i forgot to say the graph is a DAG. I think your solution is great with a undirected graph but with a DAG I see it does not work. You have any other solution? Thank you for your help